# script error JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'row' with datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables plugin for my application from the below link 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I get the below error on clicking row in table. I am unable to figure out whats wrong.

Error: JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'row'

```
 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            debugger;
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `table`?

Comment: on $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {

Comment: It should be `var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({`.

Comment: I have the same name but it throws the error.

Comment: @Chandana, can you post more code? Specifically, your code from `document.ready`.

Comment: What does `console.log(table)` give you in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share answer to see that it will be useful for users. I added `var row = table.api.row(tr);` instead of `var row = table.row(tr);` and it worked.

```
 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
 debugger;
 var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
 var row = table.row(tr);
```

Answer (score 5):

Although I can't see your code, from what you've provided it looks like you have a scoping issue.

When you define `table` inside the `$(document).ready()` it's only in the `ready` callback functions scope.

Therefore when you try to use `table` in the click handler it's defined as something else (in Chrome it's a DevTools function).

Your code should work if you move the click handler inside the `$(document).ready()` handler or if you set `window.table` from inside `$(document).ready()` instead of just `table`.

**Demo of the issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/7vs7L/

**Demo of the solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/64UgG/

Comment: You have a very good answer but my code is aligned in correct way.

Comment: @Chandana, Without more code I can't give a better one.  Do you have a demo of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

are you sure the plug in is loaded?  use both the CSS and JS CDN paths.  Check console output in Chrome.

did you remember to initialize the table with $('#myTable').dataTable()?

make sure your <table> has an id attribute #myTable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the same error by changing .dataTables to .DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

**Two possible solutions**:

1) Possible scope problem.

You might have initialized the `datatable` somewhere out of scope of the function where you are calling the `row()` method. In the javascript debugger (F12 for IE and Chrome), inspect your `datatable` variable ('table' in your case). If you see it as `'undefined'`, it is indeed the scope problem.

2) Try using the method `DataTable()` instead of `dataTable()`. It sounds strange but these two are 2 different APIs. The latter doesn't support the `'row'` method.

All the best.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function (e) {
debugger;
var tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
var row = table.row(tr);
}
</code>
```

You can't directly use 'this' in a callback method.

Comment: I want to share answer to see that it will be useful for users.

I added     var row = table.api.row(tr); instead of     var row = table.row(tr); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(selector).DataTable()` fixed this error for me..

[hope this helps.](http://datatables.net/faqs/#api)

As per documentation, `$(selector).dataTable()` return jquery object where as `$(selector).DataTable()` returns `DataTable` API Instance which has the row and other methods defined, where jquery object is used for general DOM manipulation.